# docker compose links hastname not found in python

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file with multiple servers. The link between java and database server worked and I can access my SQL server through the hostname 'db'. Now I want to send packets from my crawler to my java backend. The strategy is the same, I set the java server in links, and then pass the address by parameter. In python the parameter arrives as 'http://java:8080', but the connection fails. How do I set the links correctly and what do I need to pass to python?

Error:

```
... packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
scraper-new        |     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
scraper-new        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
scraper-new        |     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
scraper-new        | requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='java', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /book/add (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f66e4cb9be0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

my (half) docker-compose.yml

```
  java:
    container_name: bookAPI
    image: openjdk:8
    volumes:
    - ./:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command: bash -c "cd /app && java -jar bookAPI.jar  --spring.datasource.url="jdbc:mysql://db:3306/bookAPI""
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  scrapy-ebay-new:
    build: ./scraper
    container_name: scraper-new
    working_dir: /data
    volumes:
        - ./scraper/ebay-new:/data/config
    command: bash -c "chmod 777 linux.sh && dos2unix linux.sh && ./linux.sh http://java:8080 user pw"
    links:
      - java
```

linux.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    scrapy crawl ebay -a db=$1 -a user=$2 -a passwd=$3
done
```

Comment: What's your java code? is it actually listen on port 8080? (`bookAPI.jar`)

Comment: `links:` are obsolete and you don't need them at all.  Both containers should be able to use the Compose service names `java` and `scraper-ebay-new` as host names.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes this setup further.